# ImportError: No module named 'cv2' using jupyter

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to import OpenCV into my ipynb using Jupyter. I kept getting :

> ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

```
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Any idea how to import cv2 in jupyter?

Comment: Is this specifically an ipython problem? Or can you also not import this module in a regular terminal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have already installed opencv, then its possible that your notebook and your opencv library are in 2 different python environments.
The following has helped me in the past:

1. Open your notebook
2. In an new cell type:

`!pip install opencv-python`

Note, that the `!` is deliberate. This will install open-cv in your current notebook environment.

Comment: this worked but, how?? i just copied it at the beginning of the notebook and all fragments ran ok, even after deleting that line. what does it do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can type

```
which jupyter-notebook
```

if it's not in the envs of opencv-python installed, you should install jupyter in the envs:

```
condda install jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is compiled for Python 2.7. When you install it with pip, it will install 2.7. However, if you run the code with python 3, it will complain that the module is not installed.
using the command
 `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`

Solved my problem, hope it will help others

Answer (score 0):

If you are a tensorflow user on jupyter notebook. So, I can explained you how I get rid of this problem.

## On Command Line..

1. Conda activate tensorflow
   when you got this interface. (tensorflow) xx.

Now, type:
2. pip install opencv-python.

This would definitely solve the problem.